# If you land a Call Lightning bolt enhanced by Thunderbolt Strike within a mob where do the creatures go?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric

This is best understood by assuming you have 9 enemy in a 3x3 formation. I cast Call Lightning (5' AOE) targeting the center guy. Do all 9 move 10' away from me or do they all move 10' directly away from the strike point of the bolt in a sort of star burst manner? If they move away from the bolt strike point, then it would seem I could direct the push depending on which side of the target I land the bolt.

Comment: -1 this is answered unambiguously by the text of the feature that causes the effect.

Answer (score 8):

Thunderbolt Strike says that:

> when you deal lightning damage to a Large or smaller creature, you can also push it up to 10 feet away **from you**.

So if you damage 9 creatures, you push all of them away from your position, not from where you hit them.

Comment: Although I lack the complete text, if a choice is available, can *away* be *away* in *any* direction so long as the target ends up farther from the caster? For example, in addition to backward, could a foe be pushed up, down, or sideways?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Unfortunately "away from you" is all the guidance we have. Personally, I'd be inclined to interpret it as "directly away from you", but in the end it's something you'd have to take up with your GM.